# How to pass extra variable in wordpress admin post.php

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to pass variable post edit url in edit.php
by default this is the link

```
http://wordpresssite.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=62&action=edit"
```

I want to add one or more variable in this url like

```
http://wordpresssite.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=62&action=edit&post_type=newproduct"
```

when the user click anyone of the post listed in all post it will redirect to post.php with new variables how can we do this?

Comment: When you click the link where? In the admin for a custom post type?

Comment: in admin  for custom post type. actually i am using wocommerce plugin. i want add one variable in link that in the product list

Comment: In that case it should already have the `post_type` query string parameter.

Comment: in edit.php url  has parameter  'post_type'
but in post it doesn't have if i am creating new post the post_type will come but not coming in edit post

Answer (score 1):

Following code will do the job:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes_post', 'add_extra_param');

function add_extra_param( $post ){

 if(!isset($_REQUEST['new_param'])){
       ?>
       <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location = window.location.href + '&new_param=new_value';
       </script>
       <?php
 }

}
```

If you want to specify a post type before appending a parameter, you can use 'add_meta_boxes' hook. See, here the details of both the hooks i.e. 'add_meta_boxes_post' and 'add_meta_boxes': http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes

Though you don't have to deal with meta boxes here, these hooks run when you access any post in the admin area.

Comment: where i can add these

Comment: create a new plugin and put this code or simply put this in your theme's functions.php